# In struts 2 Optiontransferselect 's moveSelectedOptions doesn't seem to work

Tags: struts2

I have a optiontransferselect and the left list box has a couple of values. When I try to move the values to the right .the button doesnt work. There is no error occuring when i click on the moveselect button .The values dont move either.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the value that is being assigned . If the value of list has something like this "19090-123242" , when there is a hypen and a 1 following , the javascript seems to take it as the -1 the headerkey value and does not move it to the other box. Its a struts bug.

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem linked with **s:optiontransferselect** component of **struts-tags**. Buttons that allow move items right and Left don't work, but it only happen in Internet Explorer (IE7 and IE8). It works in FireFox and Chrome.

In my case I'm working with *Ajax* too and I have two .JSP files (one for main form and second only for optiontransferselect component) and I've included *sx:div* component of *struts-dojo-tags* in main.jsp to load *list* and *dobleList* optiontransferselect attributes based on  value selected in **s:select** components.

Thats my pom dependencies, I don't know it it can help you to find out the problem:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
       <artifactId>struts2-dojo-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thank you so much!